# How to glue months in cal-heatmap

Tags: d3.js, calendar, heatmap

I'm using [cal-heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/) to draw github like calendar as you can see in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kamisama/4aDdJ/1/)**.

```
var calendar = new CalHeatMap();
calendar.init({
    data: data,
    start: new Date(2000, 1),
    domain: "month",
    subDomain: "day",
    range: 3,
    scale: [40, 60, 80, 100]
});
```

[image]

Is it possible to remove space between each month (like the [github contribution graph](https://github.com/blog/1360-introducing-contributions))?

[image]

I have try the option `domainGutter : 0` who is not working on this special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no (not yet). Each month is in its own "domain", and can't be glued (overlapped in your case), to allow a smoother domain browsing.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'd really love to use it all glued... I saw an alternative year/day domain subdomain, but you loose the monthly labels which I need. Thanks!